# VB.Net Reverser and Substring a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, substring, reverse

I have multiple files with date and each file has different length of file name.
I would like to cut the string to only get the file name.

The way I do it in Sql is

`REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE('the full file name'), 10, LEN('the full file name')))`

**Example File names:**

`Myfile_20160708`, `MyFile123_20160708`, `Myfiles12345_20160708`

And I want the result to be:

`Myfile`, `MyFile123`, `Myfiles12345`

How do I accomplish it in VB.Net Code?

Comment: IndexOf() will tell you where the "_" appears, get the first N characters

Comment: You split on _ and take the first result.

Comment: Dim strMyString as String = ("MyFiles_20160708").Split("_")(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
Dim s As String = "Myfile_20160708"
Dim pos = s.IndexOf("_"c)
If pos >= 0 Then
    s = s.Substring(0, pos)
End If
```

uses `IndexOf` to find the location of the underscore and substring to get the part you are interested in

Comment: It would be more efficient to get the value of `s.IndexOf("_"c)` and check if it is >= 0.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - agreed. I have modified the answer to reflect this